# Concatenate certain number of rows and split into different groups

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have a query where I am concatenating some ids,but I only want to concatenate 900 and then create another row for the remaining for that same group

```
Select location_id,RTRIM(XMLCAST(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,'"'||client_id||'",')) AS CLOB),',') AS clientid from tab
GROUP BY location_id
```

Expected Output :

```
   Location_id  Clientid
    =========    =========
    100          a12,a13,a16,a17,b13,b18...
    200          c12,c34,c67,c33,c89,...if this has more than 900 ids then need another row for 200
    200          remaining ids comma separated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery against your real table to put the client IDs into buckets, and then include the bucket in the grouping:

```
select location_id,
  RTRIM(XMLCAST(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,'"'||client_id||'",')) AS CLOB),',') AS clientid
from (
  select location_id,
    client_id,
    ceil(row_number() over (partition by location_id order by client_id) / 900) as bucket
  from tab
)
group by location_id, bucket
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=142d213a9cf57b7db064185961a7543e) (split after 9 instead of 900 to demonstrate the principal)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. I will apply this.This is great!